# Can't sync to Bitcoin Network

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client, bitcoin-core-development

I'm a newbie to this community.

I have been trying to download all the blocks and be a full node, but I cannot connect to peers.

I checked my firewall and there seems no problem, and tried to add node option ( -addnode=~~) and I used some active nodes addresses in https://bitnodes.io/nodes, but none of them worked.

I am using my college network, so I requested to unblock peer-to-peer network if there are any restrictions, and they responded yes.

Also I checked my ip addresses in https://bitnodes.io/#join-the-network and it showed green.

Please help me.. I really want to be a bitcoin full node but I have no idea what's wrong.

This is my debug.log

```
'''

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z Bitcoin Core version v22.0.0 (release build)

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z Qt 5.12.11 (static), plugin=windows (static)

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z Static plugins:

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z  QWindowsIntegrationPlugin, version 330752

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z  QWindowsVistaStylePlugin, version 330752

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z Style: windowsvista / QWindowsVistaStyle

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z System: Windows 10 (10.0), x86_64-little_endian-llp64

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z Screen: \\.\DISPLAY1 1920x1080, pixel ratio=1.0

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z Screen: \\.\DISPLAY2 1920x1080, pixel ratio=1.0

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z Assuming ancestors of block 
00000000000000000008a89e854d57e5667df88f1cdef6fde2fbca1de5b639ad have valid signatures.

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z Setting nMinimumChainWork=00000000000000000000000000000000000000001fa4663bbbe19f82de910280

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z Using the 'sse4(1way),sse41(4way),avx2(8way)' SHA256 implementation

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z Using RdSeed as additional entropy source

2021-11-22T13:01:28Z Using RdRand as an additional entropy source

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z GUI: "registerShutdownBlockReason: Successfully registered: Bitcoin Core is 
not safely closed.

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Default data directory C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Using data directory D:\Bitcoin

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Config file: D:\Bitcoin\bitcoin.conf (not found, skipping)

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Using at most 125 automatic connections (2048 file descriptors available)

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 
elements

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for script execution cache, able to store 
524288 elements

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Script verification uses 15 additional threads

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z scheduler thread start

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Using wallet directory D:\Bitcoin\wallets

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z init message: verifying wallets..

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z init message: Loading banlist…

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Missing or invalid file D:\Bitcoin\banlist.dat

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Recreating the banlist database

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z SetNetworkActive: true

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Failed to read fee estimates from D:\Bitcoin\fee_estimates.dat. Continue 
anyway.

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Using /16 prefix for IP bucketing

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Cache configuration:

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z * Using 2.0 MiB for block index database

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z * Using 8.0 MiB for chain state database

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z * Using 440.0 MiB for in-memory UTXO set (plus up to 286.1 MiB of unused 
mempool space)

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z init message: Loading block index…

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Switching active chainstate to Chainstate [ibd] @ height -1 (null)

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Opening LevelDB in D:\Bitcoin\blocks\index

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Opened LevelDB successfully

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Using obfuscation key for D:\Bitcoin\blocks\index: 0000000000000000

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file = 0

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=0, size=0, 
heights=0...0, time=1970-01-01...1970-01-01)

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Checking all blk files are present...

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Initializing databases...

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Opening LevelDB in D:\Bitcoin\chainstate

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Opened LevelDB successfully

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Wrote new obfuscate key for D:\Bitcoin\chainstate: 6da95d8aa0da912c

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Using obfuscation key for D:\Bitcoin\chainstate: 6da95d8aa0da912c

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z  block index             257ms

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z loadblk thread start

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z UpdateTip: new 
best=000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f height=0 version=0x00000001 
log2_work=32.000022 tx=1 date='2009-01-03T18:15:05Z' progress=0.000000 cache=0.0MiB(0txo)

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z block tree size = 1


2021-11-22T13:01:29Z nBestHeight = 0

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Failed to open mempool file from disk. Continuing anyway.

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z loadblk thread exit

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z AddLocal(147.46.95.38:8333,1)

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Discover: DESKTOP-AT03A6B - 147.46.95.38

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Bound to 127.0.0.1:8334

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z torcontrol thread start

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Bound to [::]:8333

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Bound to 0.0.0.0:8333

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z init message: Loading P2P addresses…

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Missing or invalid file D:\Bitcoin\peers.dat

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Recreating peers.dat

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Missing or invalid file D:\Bitcoin\anchors.dat

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z 0 block-relay-only anchors will be tried for connections.

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z init message: Starting network threads…

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z net thread start

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z dnsseed thread start

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z addcon thread start

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Loading addresses from DNS seed dnsseed.bluematt.me

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z init message: loading complete

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z opencon thread start

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z msghand thread start

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z GUI: Platform customization: "windows"

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoin.sprovoost.nl

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoin.jonasschnelli.ch

2021-11-22T13:01:29Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.btc.petertodd.org

2021-11-22T13:01:30Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoin.wiz.biz

2021-11-22T13:01:30Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoinstats.com

2021-11-22T13:01:31Z Loading addresses from DNS seed dnsseed.emzy.de

2021-11-22T13:01:31Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoin.sipa.be

2021-11-22T13:01:31Z Loading addresses from DNS seed dnsseed.bitcoin.dashjr.org

2021-11-22T13:01:31Z 209 addresses found from DNS seeds

2021-11-22T13:01:31Z dnsseed thread exit
```

'''

Comment: How do you infer that you're not synchronizing and/or have no connections? What RPC output, or something in the GUI screen? Is there anything more in debug.log after the end of what you paste?

Comment: @PieterWuille / There are no peers on GUI peer tab, otherwise if I use my mobile hotspot instead of college network, I can connect to peers. / After the above log file I get these kinds of messages repeated : 2021-11-22T13:33:44Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 1935 seconds ago)

Comment: @PieterWuille / In the GUI network traffic tab, I see no data being sent or received. When I ping my IP addresses in https://bitnodes.io/#join-the-network, network traffic tab shows some data transfer.